# PowerShell and match/like/contain operators

Tags: powershell, operators

I am fairly new to PS so running into this problem. I have 2 variables:

```
    $var1= "hello"
    $var2= "hello-2018"
    
    if ($var1 -match $var2){
       #Do Something 
    }
```

I want to compare the two variables and if the $var1 has some parts of $var2, I want the code to do something. I’ve tried match, like, contains but not getting the desired output.

Comment: you have your match reversed. [*grin*] to test for A in B, you need to have A on the left ... not on the right.

Comment: ... or using string methods: `if ($var2.Contains($var1)) { }`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$var1= "hello"
$var2= "hello-2018"
    
if ($var2 -like "*$var1*"){
   #Do Something 
}
```

Also, I think https://morgantechspace.com/2016/08/powershell-check-if-string-contains-word.html would make a good read on the topic